# Selection of rows by condition

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame:

```
df_total_data2
```

which have the following columns:

```
df_total_data.columns

Index([u'BBBlink', u'Name', u'_type'], dtype='object')
```

I want to drop the all the rows which don't satisfy a given condition, in this case the condition is that the column can't contain the word `secure`
I want to drop the row at the place, not to have a function that return `None` if the condition isn't meet.

So I write this function:

```
df_total_data.apply(lambda x: 'secure' not in  x['BBBlink'],1 ).values
```

Which return a boolean array, but I don't know how to used it to drop the row.

Edit:

I got an array:

```
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,False....True])
```

Now, how can I use this array to drop the columns?

Comment: Could you provide sample `DataFrame` structure and expected output and the output or error you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you got a boolean array you can select only the rows where it is `True` by doing `df[boolean_array]` or only the rows where it is `False` by adding `~`, `df[~boolean_array]`.

As for your question, you can either use the `drop` method or do it yourself:

```
df_total_data[df_total_data.apply(lambda x: 'secure' not in  x['BBBlink'],1 ).values]
```

Just remember that this is not inplace so you need to either assign the returned value to a new dataframe or re-assign it to the existing one.

By the way, you can simplify your condition a bit:

```
 df_total_data[df_total_data['BBBlink'].apply(lambda x: 'secure' not in  x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
print df_total_data
  BBBlink  Name _type
0  secure  name     A
1  secure  name     A
2  secure  name     A
3  secure  name     A
4  secure  name     A
5     sre  name     A

print df_total_data.BBBlink.isin(['secure'])
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: BBBlink, dtype: bool

print df_total_data[df_total_data.BBBlink.isin(['secure'])]
  BBBlink  Name _type
0  secure  name     A
1  secure  name     A
2  secure  name     A
3  secure  name     A
4  secure  name     A

print df_total_data[~df_total_data.BBBlink.isin(['secure'])]
  BBBlink  Name _type
5     sre  name     A
```

But if string is with other strings you can use [str.contains](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
print df_total_data
        BBBlink  Name _type
0     secure qq  name     A
1        secure  name     A
2        secure  name     A
3        secure  name     A
4  secure aa ss  name     A
5           sre  name     A

print  df_total_data[~df_total_data.BBBlink.str.contains('secure')]
 BBBlink  Name _type
5     sre  name     A
```

Comment: This won't totally work. If there is `blah secure blah` in some row `isin` won't catch it.

Comment: I get always False, In this case 'secure' is part of a bigger string not the whole item, I didn't put that clear